# How to make a WCF service STA (single-threaded)

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, multithreading, user-interface

I have a WCF service which includes UI components, which forces me to be in STA mode.

How do I set the service behaviour to STA-mode?

---

The service uses a reference to a WPF DLL file which opens a UI window (used as view port) for picture analysis. When the service is trying to create an instance of that item (inherits from window) it throws an exception:

> The calling thread must be an STA

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing something similar to you.

My solution was to route all calls through an STA thread queue.  I used a threadsafe collection from the new [parallel framework](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=348F73FD-593D-4B3C-B055-694C50D2B0F3&displaylang=en) to queue up Actions I wanted to run on a STA thread.  I then had X number of STA threads that continually checked the queue for new actions to execute.

Comment: And, now, I'm just using a custom [SynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163321.aspx#S4) for this now.  Much better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would investigate using the [STAThread] attribute to switch the threading model.
e.g.

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] { new Host() };
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
}
```

[Description of the STAThread attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stathreadattribute.aspx)

But I'm confused why you're using UI components in a web service at all. Can you explain a bit more about why you're trying to do this?

Comment: I know the comment comes a bit late, but nonetheless - don't use this approach! Basically, this will cause deadlock with Finalizer thread so finalization will not be working causing resources leaks. I'll add url with more details soon.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001667/net-windows-service-needs-to-use-stathread

Answer (score 0):

[ServiceBehaviour](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute allows you to specify behavior. In your case for single thread you would use following:

```
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
public class Service : IService
{
}
```

You [might want to read about different](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.instancecontextmode(v=vs.110).aspx) `InstanceContextMode`s to help you better choose on how you want service to behave.

You also need to add to your `app.config` new service behavior (or edit existing one):

```
    <behavior name="wsSingleThreadServiceBehavior">
      <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="1"/>
    </behavior>
```

and in your behavior configuration in same `app.config` set behaviorConfiguration like following:

```
 <service behaviorConfiguration="wsSingleThreadServiceBehavior" name="IService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsEndpointBinding" name="ConveyancingEndpoint" contract="IService" />
  </service>
```

Hope this saves you some time