# STA thread for windows Service

Tags: c#

can I use [STAThread] for Main in windows service , does this make any problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can but it may not work as intended and can cause problems.

The best way to work around this seems to be by starting a new [Thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bkb1k2x8.aspx) and [setting its ApartmentState to STA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.setapartmentstate.aspx)

Have a read of this post for more info:

[.NET Windows Service needs to use STAThread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001667/net-windows-service-needs-to-use-stathread)